# Copying Windows installation CD to ISO on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, dvd, iso-image

I saw from another post how to do this: by using

```
cat (optical disc device) > (ISO file on regular disk)
```

e.g.,

```
cat /dev/sr0 > /z/windows7.iso
```

When I tried it, it goes partially then gets

```
cat /dev/sr0: Input/Output Error
```

This happens at about 20% completed on one of the DVDs and maybe 3% on the other one.

NB: these  are LEGAL original Windows installation DVDs that I had successfully installed on older (now defunct laptops). It is very unlikely that both DVDs became corrupted/damaged. This has to do with the copying, not with the original media.

Here is output:

```
steve@mithril:/z$ cat /dev/sr0 > /z/windowsxp.iso
cat: /dev/sr0: Input/output error
steve@mithril:/z$ ll /z/windowsxp.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steve steve 652869632 Jul  6 13:11 /z/windowsxp.iso
```

Comment: I'm confused; your question title says CD, and you show a file that is 652M bytes, which is about right for a CD.  I think maybe you're getting a complete, good copy, and a stupid, incorrect error message.  What evidence do you have to contradict my theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dd. `sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=/path/to/output/file.iso`

Comment: That yields an immediate "dd: reading '/dev/sro': Input/Output error.  But wait, i tried a second time and it appears to have worked. Will get back.

Comment: Should be sr0 not sro :D. If you did actually type sr0 then Are you sure sr0 is the device file for the CD? Did you use sudo? And have you unmounted the CD before trying this?

Comment: i just "historied" the same command it appears to have worked second time.

Comment: One of the two did "dd" properly but vmware installation failed, possibly unrelated.  But for the other, it still only completed 3% before Input/Output error. I am going to try to install directly on old computer to prove one way/other if/not it were media problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `safecopy` instead of `cat` or `dd`.

```
safecopy /dev/sr0 out.iso
```

It's in the standard software repositories, and is specifically designed for this kind of thing. From the man page:

> Safecopy  is  a  data recovery tool which tries to extract as much data as
> possible from a seekable, but problematic (i.e. damaged sectors) source - like
> floppy drives, harddisk partitions, CDs, ..., where other tools like dd would
> fail doe to I/O errors.
>
> Safecopy tries to get as much data from the source as possible without device
> dependent tricks. For example to get an ISO image  from  a  copy  protected
> or otherwise damaged CD-ROM, cdrdao and bin2iso would possibly do a better and
> faster job.

Similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138152/software-to-copy-a-scratched-cd-dvd-blueray-to-an-iso-file